# Sequence of verbs on a sentence -- should I use commas or infinitives?

Tags: verbs

Should I put the verbs in the infinitive form in the following sentence:

> As the federal auctions provide for a limited time **to** elaborate the
>   technical studies, **to** develop the project and **to** apply for the
>   necessary licenses

or should I omit the preposition "to" and instead write:

> ... to elaborate the technical studies, develop the project, and apply
>   for the necessary licenses

Comment: First off, you would say, "In this sentence..." instead of, "On this sentence..." Secondly, by you last sentence, do you mean, "As the federal auctions provide for a limited time to elaborate the technical studies, to develop and apply the project for the necessary licenses." ?

Comment: Auctions?  Is that a typo?

Comment: Could you give us a bit of context, please?  I don't completely understand the "limited time" part.

Comment: Note that you use the commas either way, because you are dealing with a series containing more than two parallel elements. So your core question is whether you can omit the second and third instances of "to" from the series. The answer to that question is yes—and essentially the same question has been asked and answered on this site in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I would take out the preposition "for" and let "a limited time" be a noun phrase as the direct object of provide.

As the first infinitive phrase begins w/ to, the others that follow w/the verb + noun phrase don't require "to" in front because they're all listed in a series. For in "apply for" would be considered a particle and in this way the parallel structure is maintained.

As the federal auctions provide a limited time to elaborate the technical studies, develop the project, and apply for the necessary licenses.

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/provide says that _provide for_ is used in legal contexts: _(Of a law) enable or allow (something to be done)_